# Swift Firebase auto-Login not showing another ViewController

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, storyboard, viewcontroller

I want to set the root-VC to the Home-VC if Firebase got an loged-In User. The console says that the user was found but the VC is not changing.

Here is my code:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

    //FirebaseConfigure
    FirebaseApp.configure()

    Auth.auth().addStateDidChangeListener { auth,user in
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)

    if user != nil {
        print("User found")

        UserService.observeUserProfile(user!.uid) { userProfile in
        UserService.currentUserProfile = userProfile
        }

        let controller = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Home")
        self.window?.rootViewController = controller
        self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
    }else{
        print("User not found")
        UserService.currentUserProfile = nil
        let controller = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Out")
        self.window?.rootViewController = controller
        self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
               }
           }

    return true
}
```

And here my Storyboard:

[image: Storyboard Home-VC IdentityInsp]

[image: Storyboard Home-VC AttributeInsp.]

Answer (score 0):

To override `rootViewController` programmatically you need to first disable the main interface of the app which defaults to `Main.storyboard` file. Here is how you do it:

1. Delete these lines from the `info.plist` file (open as source code).

```xml
<key>UIMainStoryboardFile</key>
<string>Main</string>
```

2. If your project is using `UISceneDelegate` then delete this one as well:

```xml
<key>UISceneStoryboardFile</key>
<string>Main</string>
```